# Markov Process From Semi-group

Tags: probability, probability-theory, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a complete probability space.
Suppose that $(T_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a continuous semi-group on $L^2(\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$; that is:

- $T_0(f)=f$ for every $f \in L^2(\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$,
- $T_{s+t}=T_s\circ T_t$,
- $t\mapsto T_t(f)$ is continuous for every $f \in L^2(\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$,

and $T_t=e^{tA}$ for some closed operator $A:L^2\rightarrow L^2$.  Upong rescaling $A$, can we necessarily find a Markov process $X_t$ on $\mathbb{R}$ whose law is determined by $T_t$?

Comment: By "rescaling $A$" do you mean replacing $A$ with $\lambda A$ for some $\lambda > 0$ and looking at the semigroup generated by $\lambda A$?

Comment: In your third bullet: continuous in what topology?  Also, can you state your definition of "Feller process", since different books use different definitions.

Comment: @RhysSteele yes exactly.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge I changed the requirement to Markov process only.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the law of $X_t$ is determined by $T_t$"?

Comment: That the semigroup of $X_t$ is $T_t$.